# Is there a way to track jetson nano board using gps?

Tags: python, gps, real-time, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am doing a project where I have to install the jetson nano board to a train and detect the gps location of it. But I cannot find a proper solution to include gps module to the jetson board. Please  it would be great if there is anyone who can help me with it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So from what I know exactly the best way to do so would be to get an actual gps module for the jetson nano (do not know which exact model but I think we can go with the popular 4g model) and an example of one is https://www.waveshare.com/sim7600g-h-4g-for-jetson-nano.htm but you can also do something that isn't so accurate. Little bash script, hope it helps.

So first I would ssh into your device, you can run `ifconfig` to get a little bit of an idea. It by default would be `wlan0` for the wirless module and `eth0` for the wired connection.
Let's make the file

```
touch nanoloc.sh && sudo chmod +x nanoloc.sh
```

Then just run this little script here:

```
#!/bin/bash 
#define what shell we want to use above
format="json" #xml or json
user="" #add your current user
nano_ip="$(curl ifconfig.co)"
ip_locaddr=https://freegeoip.app/$format/$nano_ip
data_file=/mnt/c/Users/$user/output.$format #change this to your expected path
touch data_file #make the file
echo data_file #make sure we have the right one
curl "$ip_locaddr" > data_file #write it out
cat data_file #let's see what it says
```

Now you should be able to see what it outputs when you run `./nanoloc.sh`

Hope this helps, also am running this from WSL (you can see from the path where it's mounted) and tested on Linux.